# Sending new order back to MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

using the JQuery sortable, and trying to send the new order back to my controller, but not having a whole lot of luck.  My view is:

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("EditTickerOrder", new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "POST", }))
{
    <div id="editableticker">
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ProjectGUID)
        <ul id="sortablediv">
            @foreach (DGI.CoBRA.Tools.BussinessObjects.CollabLibrary.TickerObjects.Ticker t in Model)
            {
                <li class="ui-state-default" id="@t.pKeyGuid.ToString()">
                    <p>@Html.CheckBox(t.pKeyGuid.ToString(), t.Display, new { @class = "activechk" }) 
                        <span style="font-weight: bold">
                            @t.Text
                        </span>
                    </p>
                </li>
            }
        </ul>
    <input type="submit" value="Save New Ticker Order" />
}
```

and my controller is:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditTickerOrder(Guid ProjectGUID, List<string> items)
{
    TickerCollectionModel TickerData = new TickerCollectionModel();
    TickerData.ProjectGUID = ProjectGUID;
    TickerData.ListAllBySession(ProjectGUID);
    return PartialView("TickerList", TickerData);
}
```

yet the `list<string> items` is always `null`.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing `foreach` loops, most definitely violating the [naming conventions](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) for your form input fields that the default model binder expects for working with collections. If you don't respect the established wire format, you cannot expect the default model binder to be able to rehydrate your models in the POST action.

In fact, why don't you use view models and editor templates? They make everything trivial in ASP.NET MVC.

So let's define a view model that will reflect your view requirements (or at least those shown in your question => you could of course enrich it with additional properties that you want to handle):

```
public class TickerViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsDisplay { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectViewModel
{
    public Guid ProjectGUID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TickerViewModel> Tickers { get; set; }
}
```

and then a controller whose responsibility is to query your DAL layer, retrieve a domain model, map the domain model into the view model we defined for this view and pass the view model to the view. Inversely, the POST action receives a view model from the view, maps the view model back into some domain model, passes the domain model to your DAL layer for processing and renders some view or redirects to a success action:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // TODO: those values come from a data layer of course
        var model = new ProjectViewModel
        {
            ProjectGUID = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Tickers = new[]
            {
                new TickerViewModel { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Text = "ticker 1" },
                new TickerViewModel { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Text = "ticker 2" },
                new TickerViewModel { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Text = "ticker 3" },
            }
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(ProjectViewModel model)
    {
        // Everything will be correctly bound here => map the view model
        // back into your domain model and pass the domain model to 
        // your DAL layer for processing ...

        return Content("Thanks for submitting");
    }
}
```

a view (it is worth noting that in this example I have used a standard form instead of AJAX but it is trivial to convert it into an AJAX form):

```
@model ProjectViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ProjectGUID)
    <div id="editableticker">
        <ul id="sortablediv">
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Tickers)
        </ul>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

and finally the corresponding editor template which will automatically be rendered for each element of the Tickers collection (`~/Views/Home/EditorTemplates/TickerViewModel.cshtml`):

```
@model TickerViewModel

<li class="ui-state-default">
    <p>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsDisplay, new { @class = "activechk" }) 
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.IsDisplay, Model.Text)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Text)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
    </p>
</li>
```

Comment: Did you test this out of curiosity?  for some reason, while i do get the correct items back in the controller, they come back in the original order, not remembering my new 'reorder'.  Does that work for you at all?

Comment: What *order* are you talking about?

Comment: The order of the tickers.  I send the ticker collection model to the view.  The user then sorts them differently than the default, and hits the submit button.  The order of the tickers that the controller received is the original/default order for some reason, not the new user-chosen order.  Not sure why.

Comment: Oh then I guess you will have to talk (show code) about this client side sorting. Did you read about the wire format for collections that the default model binder expects? You have 2 possibilities: either use indexes (in which case of course you will have to change them on the client side when reordering) or use some Guids. Please take a look at Phil Haack's article: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx in which he covers those 2 scenarios: sequential and non-sequential indexes.

Comment: Yeah, i saw the article you mentioned (thanks).  i do use GUIDs for my id values, so that my hidden input values look like:<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The pKeyGuid field is required." name="[0].pKeyGuid" type="hidden" value="9f3227b3-338d-4ba0-befe-f41d964d50ec" />
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The pKeyGuid field is required." name="[1].pKeyGuid" type="hidden" value="2f80a0d9-0262-4959-bec4-f19c1704652c" />
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The pKeyGuid field is required." name="[2].pKeyGuid" type="hidden" value="0be6c64d-f07b-450a-b81c-c76e20451726" />

Comment: No, you don't use any Guids for the names. Look at the `name` attribute of your input fields: `name="[0].pKeyGuid"`. See? Sequential indexes. When you reorder the elements in your DOM tree (with whatever client side javascript you use) you should make sure to *fix* the indexes. Or use Guids for the names. Steven Sanderson blogged about a nice custom `Html.BeginFormCollectionItem` helper allowing you to achieve that: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/